# Multi-Tenant how to overwrite default values?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, multi-tenant

I develop a multi-tenant CMS platform. In my database I have a table called styling, where the layout and colours are saved. Each new tenant gets default values for styling which are saved in a default_styling table. I don't want to duplicate the default values for each tenant, only if the tenant change the defaults.

I work with MySQL and Ruby on Rails and don't know how to design the model if the tenant has no own styling that it gets the defaults. Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your tables structure, 
if there is one record for user you can use

```
select * from
 (
  select * from user_styling limit 1
  union all
  select * from default_styling limit 1
 ) tmp
limit 1
```

If there is record in user_style that record is returned,
if not, take record from default_styling